# Web Essentials 2017 not apperaing in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: visual-studio, web-essentials

I've installed Web Essentials 2017 on Visual Studio Community 2017.
When I go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online -> Search for "Web", it's offering me the option to uninstall it.

But when I go to Tools -> Options, then 'Web Essentials' is not appearing as an option.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?